# MOSFET Ltspice determine some parameters

Tags: semiconductors

I am working on project for flyback converter using Ltspice.
Indeed, I have to insert the parameters for MOSFET inside the model but I have faced some difficulties to get the values from datasheet for these parameters:

Rd         Drain ohmic resistance.
Rs         Source ohmic resistance.
Is          Parasitic diode saturation current
Rb         Body diode resistance.

Kindly, please can you tell me how to get the values for those parameters from Datasheet. the component I work on it is STW11NM80.

I would appreciate your interest and your help.

Looking forward hearing from your side
Best regards

Answer (score 2):

The manufacturer provides a Spice model [here](http://www.st.com/web/catalog/sense_power/FM100/CL824/SC1168/PF69530#), under the "Design Resources" tab. Is this not acceptable for your needs?

Comment: Dear thank yout reply, I have found the spice model but I have also two inquiries: 1- I didnt find the whole values i need for the model. 2- how can i insert this spice model into my design.